# VS2010 copy files from bin after publish

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Solution contains 2 projects. All of them are mvc sites, but on the second site the file global.asax was deleted.The first project has reference to the second. All views, images, js and css files of the second project have attribute "copy always". In the first project in post-build event command line I added a script which copies these files from bin to another folder("Base"). 
After build everything is working fine, but after publishing with "in file system" method the files don't copy from bin folder.
"Base" folder isn't added to the first project, it is created after the first build.

Comment: Hi, what is the questing that you are asking?

Answer (score -3):

1. Set project build order
2. Copy manually in the Post-buid event like this.

`COPY "$(TargetDir)*.*" "c:\MySolution\MyProject\etc"`

Comment: "c:\MySolution\MyProject\etc" - must be dynamic string.

Comment: @zayats the answer should have used [more macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4(v=vs.110).aspx) -- if you want the project directory, use `$(ProjectDir)`

Comment: @DaveShaw (?) regardless, this post-build event doesn't seem to occur when Publishing, only when Building directly

Comment: It is not triggered when publishing, only after building.